# Make up for "in something"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Whatever we lack in free time, we more than make up for ***in
> stories*** about patients. Today in the mess* over lunch we’re trading
> stories about nonsense ‘symptoms’ that people have presented with
> (This is Going to Hurt: Secret Diaries of a Junior Doctor)

What does "in stories" mean in this sentence above?

Answer (score 1):

It means that having lost their free time, they have gained an amazing trove of stories that they can regale other people with for the rest of their lives.

To make up for something in something else means the lack of something is compensated for by the something else.

Comment: Thank you. Can I also use "with" instead of "in" ? As in "... we more than make up for with stories about patients."